# Why does Chef throw fatal error on restart request

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-zero

I'm trying to use a log filter on client.log to evaluate if Chef runs succeeded.

In the normal course of a Chef run, my recipe requests a reboot.

Chef logs:

```
  FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::Reboot: Rebooting server at a recipe's request.
```

Why does Chef throw an error with a normal reboot request? How can I prevent this error from being logged.

My reboot request looks like

```
reboot "my_reboot" do
  action :reboot_now
  reason 'There is a pending reboot.'
  only_if { reboot_pending? }
  delay_mins 0.5
end
```

Comment: Apart from above logs, there would be bit more which can state the reason. please try to run in debug to check reason or provide a bit more log on this.

Answer (score 0):

Because we want to avoid running anything further in the Chef converge and the easiest way to do that is to raise an exception.

Comment: exceptions should be exceptional. If the log isn't a reliable source of determining whether the last chef run(s) returned an error, what is?

Comment: It's a weird special case because Ruby doesn't have any other non-local code execution flow construct that would work well in this case. You'll just have to add a filter for it. Such are the realities of building software in an imperfect world :)